# How can I execute a method that does something while I'm waiting for another variable to be initialised?

Tags: java, server

I want to check a linked list of times to see if they have expired while my server has not got a connection from a client, or even every minute or two. I'm not entirely sure how this would be achieved. I would rather not have to do a threaded program but I know I will probably have to. I would appreciate any feedback/advice you guys could give me.

Here is my attempt at something that I stupidly thought would work

```
boolean connected = false;
       while(connection==null){
                System.out.println("before");
                connection = providerSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("after");
                user.checkForExpiredUsers();

            }
```

This is the method it calls in another class.

```
void checkForExpiredUsers(){
            String currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());

            for(int i =0; i<locationLat.size();i++){
                if(goodTimeDiff(currentTime,userTimeList.get(i))==false){
                    removeFromLists(i,locationLat,locationLong,destinationLat,destinationLong,userTimeList);
                    System.out.println("removed user");
                    System.out.println("The list of times: ");
                    System.out.println(userTimeList +"\n");
                }
            }

        }
```

Maybe I could run a seperate java program with just a main and while loop that calls this method?
Something like:

```
while(true){user.checkForExpiredUsers();}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using concurency utilities from *java.util.concurrent* package would be the simplest way.

---

If I understand you right the following code should help:

```
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1); // It's a barrier which holds the execution until it is counted down by another thread
    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    exec.submit(new Runnable() { // Your first job which tries to get connection

        @Override
        public void run() {
            connection = providerSocket.accept();
            latch.countDown(); // necessary to signal that it's enough to wait
        }
    });
    exec.submit(new Runnable() { // Your worker job which performs the check

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) { // this is required for proper exit
                user.checkForExpiredUsers();
            }
        }
    });
    latch.await(); // Here the main thread will pause until a connection is acquired by the first job
    exec.shutdownNow(); // Stop our jobs by setting interrupted flag for them
```

Comment: This worked. I had problems because of coding on my end! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Creating a timer task that performs the task every minute

```
public class ScheduledTask extends TimerTask {

   Date now; // to display current time

  // Add your task here
  public void run() {
        checkForExpiredUsers(); // run your code here
  }
}
```

And in the main class

```
Timer time = new Timer(); // Instantiate Timer Object
ScheduledTask st = new ScheduledTask(); 
time.schedule(st, 0, 10000); // Create Repetitively task for every 10 secs
```